# Pandoc: Prevent conversion of special characters in LaTeX

Tags: ms-word, latex, pandoc, file-conversion

I am converting a MS Word-document (`.docx`) with Pandoc to LaTeX (`.tex`). The `.docx`-file contains backslashes and brackets which Pandoc converts to the corresponding LaTeX-commands (e.g. `\textbackslash`) what I do not want.

How can I prevent Pandoc from converting special characters?

Answer (score 1):

I think pandoc is actually doing what you want. You cannot have plain backslashes in LaTeX since they would be interpreted as commands, so instead you have to use `\textbackslash{}`, which is the command to print a simple plain backslash in LaTeX. Try generating a PDF with LaTeX and you'll see what I mean.

If you actually want to include LaTeX commands in your Word file, I think that's not possible. (How would pandoc know whether the word user wanted to write a backslash or a LaTeX command?) However, you can transform your word doc to markdown, adjust it (in pandoc markdown you actually can include [raw TeX](http://pandoc.org/README.html#raw-tex)), then export it to LaTeX.

```
pandoc input.docx -o file.md
# edit file.md now
pandoc file.md -o output.tex
```

For a more automated solution, you could look into [pandoc filters](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html). Then it's up to you how to solve the ambiguity of backslashes...

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right but I have LaTeX commands in my Word document which I want to preserve.

Comment: I see, your "corresponding LaTeX-commands" led me astray... anyway, see my edit.